How to make an Azure Container Registry (ACR) public so that anyone can pull images?
I want to make my Azure Container Registry (ACR) public so that anyone can pull images from it without needing authentication. How can I do this?

To enable anonymous pull access on an Azure Container Registry (ACR), you can follow the steps below:
Prerequisites:

You need to be using the Standard or Premium tier of Azure Container
Registry, as the anonymous pull feature is available only in these
tiers.

Note: By default, access to pull or push images from an Azure Container Registry is only available to authenticated users.
To allow everyone (even unauthenticated users) to pull images, you can enable anonymous pull access using the Azure CLI.
Run the following command in the Azure CLI:
az acr update --name <yourRegistryName> --anonymous-pull-enabled true

Replace  with the name of your Azure Container Registry.
Optional:
If you want to disable anonymous pull access later, you can run the following command:
az acr update --name <yourRegistryName> --anonymous-pull-enabled false

I tried to find a way to do by Azure Portal(GUI) but didn't find way. If you know then please let me know.
